# Add and remove classes in javascript without jquery

Tags: javascript

i have some paragraphs. At first one of that should have red color and after click it should become black, and clicked one should become red. I need to change red each paragraph when it is clicked and remove the class when another one is clicked. I should do it with javascript

```js
var p = document.querySelectorAll("p");
for( var i = 0; i < p.length; i++ ){
 p[i].addEventListener("click", makeRed);
 p[0].classList.add("active");
}

function makeRed(){
 p[0].classList.remove("active");

 if( this.classList.contains("active")){
  this.classList.remove("active");
    } else{
     this.classList.add("active");
    }
    
}
```

```css
 .active{
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<p>Text First</p>
<p>Text Second</p>
<p>Text Third</p>
```

Comment: @Grégory NEUT non) je ne veux pas ecrire comme ca, merci!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is good, just have a little logical problem :)

```js
var p = document.querySelectorAll("p");
for( var i = 0; i < p.length; i++ ){
 p[i].addEventListener("click", makeRed);
 p[0].classList.add("active");
}

function makeRed(){
 if( this.classList.contains("active")){
  this.classList.remove("active");
    } else{
        for( var i = 0; i < p.length; i++ ){
            p[i].classList.remove("active");
        } 
     this.classList.add("active");
    }
    
}
```

```css
 .active{
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<p class="active">Text First</p>
<p>Text Second</p>
<p>Text Third</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below solution,

```js
var p = document.querySelectorAll("p");
for( var i = 0; i < p.length; i++ ){
   
 p[i].addEventListener("click", makeRed);
 p[0].classList.add("active");
}

function makeRed(){
   var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".active");
    [].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
      el.classList.remove("active");
    });
 if( this.classList.contains("active")){
  this.classList.remove("active");
    } else{
     this.classList.add("active");
    }
    
}
```

```css
.active{
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<p>Text First</p>
<p>Text Second</p>
<p>Text Third</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all elements and reset their class by removing `active` and then simply add class to current element.

```js
var p = document.querySelectorAll("p");
for( var i = 0; i < p.length; i++ ){
 p[i].addEventListener("click", makeRed);
 p[0].classList.add("active");
}

function makeRed(){     
    [...document.querySelectorAll('p')]
      .map(elem => elem.classList.remove("active"));
    this.classList.add("active");        
}
```

```css
 .active{
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<p>Text First</p>
<p>Text Second</p>
<p>Text Third</p>
```